# Navigating into the default main route in chrome extension (React)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-router

I'm building a new chrome extension using ReactJS, and I'm trying to redirect on '/' (default) to an existing route using the  component of react-router.
For some reason, I can see it when I compile it to localhost, but when I upload it as a chrome extension I can't see it anymore.

What I thought about is that maybe there is another route that is in use as the main route in chrome extension instead of '/'.

I tried to console.log it but for some reason, it is not showing me the logs.

Thanks!

```
  <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={() => <Redirect to="/navigatehere" /> }
        />
        <Route
          path="/navigatehere"
          exact
          render={() => <NavigateHere />}
        />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: AFAIK you should switch the router into hash mode for extensions.

Comment: actually, it works fine with all the rest of the routers, are you sure? @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0):

First Of all you need `Switch` to use `exact` prop.

You can import it like this.

```
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route}

// Then you have to use

<BrowserRouter>
   <div>
      <Switch>
       <Route path='/' exact /*render Whatever you want after this . . .*/ />
      </Switch>
   </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Second of all, I use `component` prop instead of `render()`.

Like this -

```
import DummyComponent from './DummyFolder/DummyComponent;
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route}

<BrowserRouter>
   <div>
      <Switch>
       <Route path='/' exact component={DummyComponent}/> // This will render the component in the respective path
      </Switch>
   </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

However `render()` should also work for you if you use `<Switch>`. It is working without `Switch` for rest of the router because you are not specfing `path` as '/' for all the `<Route />`. If you want to route to '/', then `Switch` is compulsory. You can also refer DevEd 's YouTube channel for more understanding. He has made an exclusive video on React Router. Check that out [Here](https://youtu.be/Law7wfdg_ls) ◀ ◀ ◀.

Comment: I've tried your solution, and it seems still not to work.
It works when I run it with the npm locally, but not when it runs as a chrome extension.